# Not able to replace all for dollar sign

Tags: java

can anyone advise why i encountered index out of bouns exception when running this method to replace the value by `$` sign?

E.g. i pass in a message `$$vmdomodm$$`

```
message = message.replaceAll("&#36;", "$");
```

I tried to look at this forum thread but couldnt understand the content

http://www.coderanch.com/t/383666/java/java/String-replaceAll

Comment: You are replaceing $ with $ which means nothing can change. That does not make sense.

Comment: `replaceAll` takes a regular expression as an argument and the expression `$` matches the end of a line. What exactly do you expect as a result?

Comment: Sorry i have updated it should be: message = message.replaceAll("&#36;", "$");

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is special character you need to use escape character

Try with this `\\$`

and it doesn't make sense in your code you are trying to replacing the content with same

```
String message = "$$hello world $$";
message = message.replaceAll("\\$", "_");
System.out.println(message);
```

**output**

```
__hello world __
```

---

**Update**

```
   String message = "&#36;hello world $$";
   message = message.replaceAll("&#36;", "\\$");
   System.out.println(message);
```

**output**

```
 $hello world $$
```

Comment: Sorry i have updated it should be: message = message.replaceAll("&#36;", "$");

Comment: I am trying to convert the html entity code &#36; to its ASCII code equivalent.

Comment: What is so special about this character that i need to escape it?

Comment: It is a regex pattern character

Comment: when I try this I am getting error: Illegal group reference

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not really using any regex so instead of replaceAll you should be using [String#replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method like this:

```
message = message.replace("&#36;", "$");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!str.isempty() && str.contains("$")){
   str = str.replaceAll("\\$", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\$"))
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This is actually the only solution that works. :thumbsup: I'd hire this guy! :-)

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering around with replaceAll() and never getting what I wanted I figured it would be easier to write a function to escape the dollar signs.

```
public static String escapeDollarSign(String value) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$");
    int off = 0;
    while (true) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(value.substring(off));
        if (!m.find()) break;
        int moff = m.start();
        String left = value.substring(0, off+moff);
        String right = value.substring(off+moff+1, value.length());
        value = left+"\\$"+right;
        off += moff+1+1;
    }

    return value;
}
```

e.g.
`$re$gex $can $ b$e a$ pain$`
becomes
`\$re\$gex \$can \$ b\$e a\$ pain\$`