# Java String.replaceAll doesn't replace a dollar

Tags: java

I want to know why only `$` is throwing `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference` exception and not any other special character :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "asdf ok done %test%";
    String as=s.replaceAll("%test%", "$dsf");
    System.out.println(as);
}
```

this can be overcome by a `\\` added before the `$` but why only for this character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to replace all for dollar sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679930/not-able-to-replace-all-for-dollar-sign)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can capture groups in the first parameter, and use them in the second parameter to mean "insert the bit you matched here":

```
String as = s.replaceAll("hello (.*) (\\d*)", "goodbye $2 $1");
```

When you use a `$`, the regex engine thinks you are trying to refer to such a group. Adding `\\` escapes it, making it a literal dollar.

This is described in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see `Matcher.replaceAll`. Use [`Matcher.escapeReplacement(java.lang.String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String))to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.)

Comment: if the second argument is dynamic, it could be pre-escaped with a non-regexpr replace like `.replace("$", "\\$")`, so in this example `String as=s.replaceAll("%test%", "$dsf".replace("$", "\\$") );`

Comment: @ElvisCiotti a more robust approach would be to use [`Matcher.quoteReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer in the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string;

See [also](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-)

Comment: this is more of a comment i feel @anton